# Magento blank page but die working

Tags: magento-1.9, error

Hi I have previously working magento site.I just uninstall and reinstalled the php.Now site is giving a blank page but in the magento 1.9 index.php die is working but not showing any error. I have tried display_errors and other things.Please help me to solve the problem ASAP. Also there is not any error log. Can I find some error log. Thanks.

Comment: you can check error log

Comment: Which PHP version you are using for Magento 1.9?

Comment: php 5.6. I can't see any error in logs.

Comment: BTW Where can I check ther error?

Comment: @Charanjeet check my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can add below code in `index.php` in top and after check it

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

Comment: Array
(
    [type] => 1
    [message] => Class 'SimpleXMLElement' not found
    [file] => /var/www/gocleaning.nl/includes/src/__default.php
    [line] => 24707
)

Comment: this is the output

Comment: run below command : 
`apt install php5.6-xml`
After it reload and restart apache2 service :

`service apache2 reload  `

`service apache2 restart`

Comment: i am using nginx server and centos 7. What install php-xml will do?

Comment: @Charanjeet  try `sudo apt-get install php-xml`
please check this linnk https://ajayogal.wordpress.com/2017/06/05/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-5-6-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: please keep in touch I am new to this and assigned this task to do today. Please keep help me :) .Thanks

Comment: The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

Trace:
#0 /var/www/gocleaning.nl/includes/src/__default.php(52764): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /var/www/gocleaning.nl/includes/src/__default.php(29238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)

Comment: now getting this above error

Comment: you can find this error in google

Comment: if any query ask another question for not mixing up

Comment: Very much thanks. You are my lifesaver. Your answer solved my problem in just few minutes. Thanks very much again.

Answer (score 1):

You will find log files

> var/log

In this folder there are **exception.log** and **system.log** files

Plus there is **report** folder as well in which you get the error in report number wise file

I hope this will find. if you still have any difficulty please let me know

Comment: No there is not any helpful error all are old errors

Comment: @Charanjeet you ask for magento 1.9 errors log. so I gave you the path of errors log. if you still haven't got any error then try to add this code  error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); in your magento code index.php file

Comment: I already tried this but no luck.

Comment: @Charanjeet brother oh I got you. You should also enable the error log from admin backend check this tutorial  https://www.magestore.com/magento-basic-setting/how-to-enable-error-and-exception-logging-in-magento

Comment: Once you done please let me know

Comment: The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded Trace: #0 /var/www/gocleaning.nl/includes/src/__default.php(52764): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2) #1 /var/www/gocleaning.nl/includes/src/__default.php(29238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array

Comment: getting this error please help me

Comment: Thanks know it is solved. I only installed the pdo extension.