# Product Page 404 error, after moving website

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, 404

I have created a testing version of my website, in the same server, but using a different domain name. Frontend and backend works ok, but product pages redirect to

> 404 page error

I have tried:

> - clearing cache
> - reindexing data
> - re-save products
> - cleared catalog url rewrites
> - disabling all third-party modules.
> - resetting directory permissions

Nothing worked.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you are facing problem in magento1?

Comment: yes this is magento 1.9

Comment: you can add this code in index.php and after check what is error
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/259909/68695

Comment: I don't think that there's an error, I'm just being redirected to magento's 404 page. there are no errors in logs either.

Comment: I assume you have duplicated your database since you use another domain and this is stored in the database. Did you check the url rewrite table? Do you find your requets path there? Do the direct call of the product page `catalog/product/view/id/XXX` work for the product?

Comment: I found the requests in rewrite  table and they seemed correct. I tried to delete some of them but it had no effect. Attempting to browse `catalog/product/view/id/XXX` also redirects to 404 error page.

Comment: If you don't see any exception in your exception.log, that looks like your product is not available in that store (either visibility doesn't allow it or the product is not assigned to website). If you have created a new website in the same database I'm quite sure the last option is the problem

Comment: I have only one website with one store/store view in it. Products are in stock, assigned to categories, enabled, visible in catalog and categories list. But still there's 404 in product page

Answer (score 0):

It seems that issue was caused by this error found in exception log:

> cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_name`.`report_event`, CONSTRA...”

In order to solve this, I followed instructions here:

https://www.mttr.io/blog/web-development/magento-cannot-add-or-update-a-child-row-report-event/

and run this query in my database:

```
INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 1);
```